# chroot root jail with where you an only su out to registed user

Tags: linux, ssh, security, unix, chroot

Can i ask for some advice about securing ssh logins.

Is this a good way.

I want to have only one user allowed to connect to our remote servers(AllowUser in sshd.conf)Using ssh keys and NoPasswords.
This user connect to a restricted shell withn a chroot, the only command allowed is su - (Own User)

Does this work and how would i go about the latter part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `su` within `chroot` - to do so would invalidate the whole point of the `chroot` mechanism, which is isolation.

The closest I think you could come to implementing this, is to login chrooted, and then login again to `localhost` as the user, via `ssh` or similar.

You could then run another `sshd` on a separate port, or otherwise restrict the login location to be "localhost only".